# Azure ML Recommendations

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to use Azure ML to find related products using information from receipts from a store.

I got a file of reciepts:

```
44366,136778
79619,88975
78861,78864
53395,78129,78786,79295,79353,79406,79408,79417,85829,136712
32340,33973
31897,32905
32476,32697,33202,33344,33879,34237,34422,48175,55486,55490,55498
17800
32476,32697,33202,33344,33879,34237,34422,48175,55490,55497,55498,55503
47098
136974
85832
```

Each row represent one receipt and each number is a product id.

Given a product id I want to get a list of similar products, i.e. products that was bought together by other customers.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how do to this?

Answer (score 2):

This seems a good fit for their frequently bought together service (https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/amla/mba). You may have to preprocess the dataset to get it in the required format. This service has a web UI as well: https://marketbasket.cloudapp.net/

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical problem for Recommender, you can use a model called Machbox recommender to cover such a problem.
Recommender typically use Scoring about items to propose and the use some tricky calculation to predict scores for items users had not scored yet ( a score would be typically 1 user bought the item, 0 he did not)
If you need more details let me know ..(you have access to a free version of Azure ML where you can try all this)
Regards

Comment: Please don't leave answers such as 'If you need more details let me know'. Try to elaborate and use examples, so future Googlers and members can use your answer.. Remember Stack Overflow is not a forum.. Thanks. :)